# LogStash: iterate array using exec input plugin

Tags: logstash, xml

I'm using the following logstash config file to request and parse xml response from a server:

```
input {
  exec {
    command => "/usr/bin/curl -s http://%{host}/api/messages"
    interval => 10
    type => "mytype"
  }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "mytype" {
    xml {
      source => "message"
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to get this response from several servers and correctly tag the host variable in this log entry with their IP?